# Google is showing thumbnail image with page URL on mobile version

Tags: seo, google-search, wordpress, thumbnail, yoast

[image]

Google is showing thumbnail image on the right with page url on mobile version. Yoast SEO plugin using for SEO Optimization purpose. How to remove this image so google will not show the image with page URL?

Answer (score 3):

Google often [tests this](https://www.seroundtable.com/google-testing-image-thumbnails-snippets-24649.html), sometimes showing thumbnails, and other times not.

It's not clear how it decides which to show and I think its just picking one one of the images from your page, as when I check, I see a different image

(this one: https://i1.wp.com/chacc.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2018/06/Bark-Professional-Chacc.png?zoom=2&resize=152%2C82&ssl=1)

So I don't think its Yoast plugin causing this.

You could try implementing Schema for the company logo, and see if that influences which image it picks.

More info here: [Specify the image Google Search uses for your organization's logo in Search results and in the Knowledge Graph.](https://developers.google.com/search/docs/data-types/logo)

Comment: Thanks for the answer @Max. What should I do to solve this issue?

Comment: *You could try implementing Schema for the company logo, and see if that influences which image it picks.* This is likely the answer! Cheers!!